# For a growing data feed in R, how can two time lengths be calculated based on "time to peak" and "time back to baseline"?

Tags: r, append, lapply

[image: Two time lengths to measured: departure from baseline range to peak, and peak back to baseline]

How can the following be accomplished with R?

1. Connect a constantly changing data source (e.g. https://goo.gl/XCM6yG) into R,
2. Measure time once prices start to rise consistently from initial baseline range to peak (represented by the green horizontal line),
3. Measure time from peak back to baseline range (the teal line)

Note: "Departure from baseline range" (unless there is a better mathematical way) defined as at least the most recent 5 prices all being over 3 standard deviations above the mean of the latest 200 prices

Comment: The answer is *"it depends"*, but I'm not certain exactly how you intend *R* to "monitor a vector". Is there a vector growing somewhere, and does *R* have the ability to "see" it and monitor its growth? Is it an API endpoint? Lots of ways this can go (and ways it can trip/fail). For the rest of the questions, it is almost certainly 42. Perhaps now is a good time to come up with a better question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a really vague questions with an unknown use case but... here we go.

1. Monitoring in what way?  The length?  That's what I did
2. The vector has over 200 values we can take the mean, so we need a control flow for that part.
3. I added in some noise which basically says force the behavior you want to calculate ( ifelse(i %in% 996:1000, 100, 0) which means, if the iterator is in 996 to 1000, add 100 to the random normal i generated). We set a counter and check if each value is about 3 sd of the vector values, if so we record the time.
4. At each input of the data...check if the current value is the max value... now this is more tricky since we would have to look at the trend.  This is beyond the scope of my assistance.
5. Up to you to figure out since I don't really understand

   ```
    vec <- vecmean <- val5 <- c()
    counter <- 0 
   for(i in 1:1000){        
   vec[i] <- rnorm(1) + ifelse(i %in% 996:1000, 100, 0)
   Sys.sleep(.001)  # change to 1 second 
   #1 
   cat('The vector has',length(vec),'values within...\n')

   #2
   if(length(vec)>200){
     vecmean <- c(vecmean, mean(vec[(i-200):i]))
     cat('The mean of the last 200 observations is ',
         format(vecmean[length(vecmean)], digits =2),'\n')

     #3 
     upr <- vecmean[length(vecmean)] + 3*sd(vec)
     if(vec[i] > upr){
       counter <- counter + 1
     } else{
       counter <- 0
     }
     if(counter > 4){
       cat('Last 5 values greater than 3sd aboving the rolling mean!\n')
       val5 <- Sys.time()
       cat("Timestamp:",as.character(val5),'\n')
     }
   }
   # 4
   theMax <- max(vec)
   if(vec[i] == theMax & !is.null(val5) ){
     valMax <- Sys.time()
     valDiff <- valMax - val5
     cat('The time difference between the first flag and second is', as.character(valDiff),'\n')
   }


   }
   ```

Comment: Appreciate the help, @mr.joshuagordon - I can see this is not a simple task!

I updated my original post to clarify my questions based on your feedback. Hopefully the two timeframes desired are more clear now. Essentially one time recording from (just above) baseline up to peak, and a second time recording from peak to (just below) baseline.

Why do you add 100 to the random normal generated?